# RethinkDb: Has many query

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Have two table, Quiz and Questions

Quiz table store questions id and its display position.
Display position is different for every Quiz.

Quiz table:

```
{
 id: '1'
 name: 'Quiz 1'
 questions: [
  {
   question_id: '1',
   position: 4
  },
  {
   question_id: '2',
   position: 1
  },
  ......
 ]
}
...
```

Question Table:

```
[
 {
  id: '1',
  title: 'Question 1'
 },
 {
  id: '2'
  title: 'Question 2'
 }
]
```

I want the the return result like this

```
{
 id: '1',
 name: 'Quiz 1',
 questions: [
   {
    position: 4,
    title: 'Question 1'
   },
   {
    position: 1,
    title: 'Question 2'
   }
 ]
}
```

How can i get the desired result?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired result by using following query

```
r.db('database').table("quizes").get(id)
  .do((quiz) => {
    return quiz.merge({'questions': quiz('questions').map((q) => {
     return q.merge((r.db('database').table('questions').get(q('id')).without('id')))
    })
   })
 })
```